# VueJS SPA | При переходах ломается recaptcha invisible

Tags: vue.js, recaptcha, spa

*Сегодня прям день когда ломается всё..*

Использую следующий пакет: [vue-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha)

По ходу развития приложения понял что отвалилась часть авторизации.

Имеется компонент **Auth.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="auth">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Auth'
    }
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
    @import "../../sass/auth.sass"
</style>
```

В нём ничего нет, он выступает объединяющим компонентом двух дочерних: **Login**, **Register**

Собственно в **Login.vue** или **Register.vue** подключаю компонент и инициализирую его:

```
<vue-recaptcha
    :loadRecaptchaScript="false"
    ref="invisibleRecaptcha"
    @verify="handle"
    size="invisible"
    :sitekey="recaptcha_site_key"/>
```

Он работает, но с ним имеются проблемы. Если переходить с **register** в **login** и обратно, создаются в **DOM** блоки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это ничто иное как **iframe invisible recaptcha**.

Я пробовал выносить создание на уровень выше относительно компонента: **login > auth > app** прописывая:

```
<vue-recaptcha
    :loadRecaptchaScript="true"
    ref="invisibleRecaptcha"
    size="invisible"
    :sitekey="recaptcha_site_key"/>
```

**loadRecaptchaScript = true**

Соответственно в остальных местах (**Register**/**Login**) я ставил **false**, чтобы компонент не подгружал скрипт повторно. Но это не мешает ему создавать блоки в **DOM**.

Может есть нормальные библиотеки? Способы?
Мне не сложно самому написать данный компонент, но как правильно организовать данное решение проблемы? Кто-то сталкивался с подобным на **SPA**?

Были ли у вас проблемы с рекапчей при создании приложения на SPA? Может я что-то не так делаю и мне стоит полностью пересмотреть подключение модуля капчи?

Comment: Попробуйте при переключении роута уничтожать капчу.
Но мне кажется проблема в пакете, он не должен себя так вести

Comment: @ryzen, может стоит самому написать front часть для капчи? Просто хотел узнать у других разработчиков, нет ли какого-то пакета или быть может проблема вовсе не во мне?

Comment: В общем есть еще метод reset() у капчи, может он обновляет DOM, а не создает компоненты заново, нашел вот статейку - https://habr.com/ru/post/443370/. Я еще до капчи у себя в SPA не дошел, по этому второй день тоже интересуюсь твоим вопросом)

Comment: @ryzen reset() я использую только при отправке запроса. То есть, я формирую данные, передаю в vuex, отсылаю их post запросом на API и если что-то не валидно, делаю reset. Я ещё вчера вечером подумывал над написанием своего компонента, который будет уносить за собой созданный <script></script> рекапчи, чтобы работало только там, где я вызываю. Вот всё ещё думаю, но всё меньше и меньше сомнений чтобы это начать делать. В компоненте vue-recaptcha я заметил то, что он создаёт новые блоки в DOM и это рушит систему мне, после десятка переходов туда-сюда, элементов просто много.

Comment: ну тут нужно значит удалять этот элемент при смене роута, но это чёт не очень затея как по мне))

Comment: @ryzen данный компонент не предоставляет возможности удалять то что он насоздавал. Видимо это большая проблема будет в SPA приложении. В обычное приложение может и пойдёт, но не в SPA. Учтите это, а я займусь делом